# generate release name from values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I got a helm template that generates a deployment
I need a separate deployment for each combination of 3 values the chart gets as parameters

```
helm upgrade -i release_name folder --set a=x --set b=y --set c=z
```

So i need release name to be a template based on a,b,c `{.Values.a},{.Values.b}{.Values.c}`

Is there any way to do something like this?
the best way I found so far is an external python script that generates the release name and passes the parameters.

I know I can do the other way around and split the

```
$parts := split "." .Release.Name
$parts._0
```

and use it as params but I would really like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Helm [Named Template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#helm) to define a function that generate the release name for the desired values. Then, you can use that template function in your resource YAML.

For example, lets define a function in `_helpers.tpl` file.

```
{{- define "release.name" -}}
{{- list .Values.a .Values.b .Values.c | join "-" }}
{{- end }}
```

Now, use this template function as your release name in your resource YAML file. For example,

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ include "release.name" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    chart: ni-filecleaner
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
```